# Apt-get install showing: errors were encounterd while processing: docutils-common python-docutils golismero

Tags: 16.04, apt, python, dpkg

Trying to install anything with `sudo apt-get install`, I receive this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
docutils-common
python-docutils
golismero
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The complete output from `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hardening-includes libandroid-properties1 libasn1-8-heimdal libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libdouble-conversion1v5 libgssapi3-heimdal libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libhardware2 libhcrypto4-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhud2 libhx509-5-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libhybris libhybris-common1 libkrb5-26-heimdal
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libmeanwhile1 libmedia1 libmng2 libqt5feedback5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5quicktest5 libqt5test5 libroken18-heimdal libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libunity-action-qt1
  libwind0-heimdal libwind0-heimdal:i386 libx86-1 libzephyr4 linux-headers-4.4.0-51 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-51-generic pidgin-data plainbox-provider-checkbox plainbox-provider-resource-generic plainbox-secure-policy pm-utils pyotherside python3-checkbox-support python3-guacamole
  python3-jinja2 python3-padme python3-plainbox python3-xlsxwriter qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qtfeedback
  qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 qml-module-qttest qml-module-qtwebkit qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
  qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics qmlscene qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin qtdeclarative5-test-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
  suru-icon-theme ubuntu-core-launcher ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme vbetool
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up docutils-common (0.12+dfsg-2) ...
Unknown option: sort
Usage:
   update-xmlcatalog <options> --add --root --type <type> \
                                                --id <id> --package <package>
   update-xmlcatalog <options> --del --root --type <type> \
                                                --id <id>

   update-xmlcatalog <options> --add --package <package> --type <type> \
                                                --id <id> --local <local>
   update-xmlcatalog <options> --del --package <package> --type <type> \
                                                --id <id>

   update-xmlcatalog <options> --add --local <local> --type <type> \
                                                --id <id> --file <file>
   update-xmlcatalog <options> --del --local <local> --type <type> \
                                                --id <id>

   update-xmlcatalog --help

With:
    --file <file>       = a local filename
    --id <id>           = catalog entry idenitifier
    --local <local>     = a local XML catalog
    --package <package> = a package XML catalog
    --root              = the root XML catalog (= /etc/xml/catalog)
    --type <type>       = catalog entry type (= public, system, uri)

Options:
    --verbose = be verbose

dpkg: error processing package docutils-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-docutils:
 python-docutils depends on docutils-common (= 0.12+dfsg-2); however:
  Package docutils-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-docutils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of golismero:
 golismero depends on python-docutils; however:
  Package python-docutils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package golismero (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.29) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docutils-common
 python-docutils
 golismero
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to force remove the packages `docutils-common` `python-docutils` `golismero`

1. First remove the packages form `dpkg/info` directory

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/docutils-common* python-docutils* golismero*
   ```
2. Then use `--force-remove` to remove them all completely

   ```
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq docutils-common python-docutils golismero
   ```

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot. Not showing up anymore on sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: now you can just do `sudo apt-get update` with errors free